# SQL Server : populate MAX(column) value with 0 for non existing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to return 0 for MAX_TIER for non existing rows in table

This is my code so far :

```
SELECT   
    LAST_YARD_BAY, LAST_YARD_ROW, MAX(LAST_YARD_TIER) as MAX_TIER
FROM
    Handlift
WHERE 
    HDCHKOUTD_OUT IS NULL 
    AND LIFLAG = 'A'
    AND LAST_YARD_PARK = 'J1'
GROUP BY 
    LAST_YARD_BAY, LAST_YARD_ROW
ORDER BY 
    LAST_YARD_BAY, LAST_YARD_ROW;
```

The screenshot shows a part of the result:

[image]

For Bay `005` I have `MAX_TIER` for ROWS `00A`to `00G`, but for Bay `007` I have only 3 Rows: `00E`,`00F` and `00G`.

How can I populate `MAX_TIER` with value 0 for the 4 missing rows (`00A`, `00B`, `00C` and `00D`) of Bay `007` and the other missing rows?

Comment: If the row doesn't exist, where are you expecting the value to come from? Do you have another table with all the values you want to return? Sample data and expected results are far more useful, as a dataset which shows the wrong data from your attempt(s) dosen't tell us what you want or what what you have looks like.

Comment: What does your schema look like? What is the data type of `MAX_TIER`? Is it supposed to be an integer value that should be 2 digits, or is it a varchar value that can have more than just number characters? Since you are aggregating, I'm guessing you have a lot more data in the `handlift` table. Can you provide some example data? Something like sqlfiddle.com works very well for this.

Comment: Also, do you always want `LAST_YARD_ROW` to show records for `00A` through `00G`, or can there be other values?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CROSS JOIN` to generate the rows and a `LEFT JOIN` to bring in the results:

```
SELECT lyb.LAST_YARD_BAY, lyr.LAST_YARD_ROW, 
       COALESCE(MAX(LAST_YARD_TIER), 0) as MAX_TIER
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LAST_YARD_BAY FROM Handlift) lyb CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT LAST_YARD_ROW FROM Handlift) lyr LEFT JOIN
     Handlift hl
     ON hl.LAST_YARD_BAY = lyb.LAST_YARD_BAY AND
        hl.LAST_YARD_ROW = lyr.LAST_YARD_ROW AND
        hl.HDCHKOUTD_OUT IS NULL AND
        hl.LIFLAG = 'A' AND
        hl.LAST_YARD_PARK = 'J1'
GROUP BY lyb.LAST_YARD_BAY, lyr.LAST_YARD_ROW
ORDER BY lyr.LAST_YARD_BAY, lyr.LAST_YARD_ROW;
```

I'm not sure exactly how the filtering is supposed to work.  You may want to limit the results in the subqueries, so they filter which bays and rows you get.

Comment: This is not working. I want to fill `MAX_TIER` with `0` for non existing rows.

Comment: @mehdilag . . . Just use `COALESCE()` to replace the value.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what are you looking for?

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE LastYardBay = '005'
UNION
SELECT '007',
       T1.LastYardRow,
       ISNULL(T2.MaxTier, 0)
FROM 
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM T
      WHERE LastYardBay = '005'
    ) T1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM T
      WHERE LastYardBay = '007'
    ) T2
ON T1.LastYardRow = T2.LastYardRow;
```

**Returns:**

```
+-------------+-------------+---------+
| LastYardBay | LastYardRow | MaxTier |
+-------------+-------------+---------+
|         005 | 00A         |       3 |
|         005 | 00B         |       4 |
|         005 | 00C         |       1 |
|         005 | 00D         |       1 |
|         005 | 00E         |       1 |
|         005 | 00F         |       4 |
|         005 | 00G         |       1 |
|         007 | 00A         |       0 |
|         007 | 00B         |       0 |
|         007 | 00C         |       0 |
|         007 | 00D         |       0 |
|         007 | 00E         |       5 |
|         007 | 00F         |       4 |
|         007 | 00G         |       1 |
+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fb8b19ff59b898cca74df0d3a43bae78)**

---

*UPDATE:*

Since you already have `'005'` you need just a `CROSS JOIN` then filter with `IS NULL` as

```
WITH A AS
(
SELECT       T1.LastYardBay LYB1,
             T1.LastYardRow LYR1,
             T1.MaxTier MT1,
             T2.LastYardBay LYB2,
             T2.LastYardRow LYR2,
             T2.MaxTier MT2
FROM 
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM T
      WHERE LastYardBay = '005'
    ) T1
    CROSS JOIN
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM T
      WHERE LastYardBay != '005'
    ) T2
)
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE LastYardBay = '005'
UNION
SELECT  LYB2,
        LYR1,   
        CASE WHEN LYR2 = LYR1 THEN MT2 ELSE 0 END MT
FROM A LEFT JOIN T ON A.LYB2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: This is the result I want, but for all the Bays not only 007 and 005.

Comment: I don't have MaxTier in table, `MAX(LAST_YARD_TIER) as MAX_TIER`

Comment: I tried your query and I've got some duplicated fields.                                       [link](https://ibb.co/wRzHg3x)
[link](https://ibb.co/g7jh3Kf)