# SQL Server : insert missing rows to be a total of 7 for each BAY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert missing records with a value of 0 in the column `TOP_TIER`
to complete a total of 7 records for every `LAST_YARD BAY` value.

This is my simple query:

```
SELECT        
    LAST_YARD_BAY, LAST_YARD_ROW, TOP_TIER 
FROM
    MAX_TIER;
```

And this is a part of the result set:

[image]]

As you can see I have 7 records (00A, 00B, 00C, 00D, 00E, 00F, 00G) for BAY `005`, same for BAY `009` and `012`, but not for BAY `007` (00E, 00F, 00G) and so many others that are not shown in the picture.

My question is: how can I insert the missing records with a value of 0 in `TOP_TIER` so that I can get the following: (for all Bays not just Bay `007`)

```
007    00A      0
007    00B      0
007    00C      0
007    00D      0
007    00E      05
007    00F      04
007    00G      01
```

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56525314/sql-server-populate-maxcolumn-value-with-0-for-non-existing-rows?

Comment: And what were wrong with the answers you received there? If they didn't fulfil the requirement you should be stating so in the comments. if they did, you should be marking them as the solution and then explaining here how this expands on the existing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cross join the `lasr_yard_bay`s with the `last_yard_row`s to get the complete set. With a `NOT EXISTS` you can the filter out only the missing ones and insert them.

```
INSERT INTO max_tier
            (last_yard_bay,
             last_yard_row,
             top_tier)
            SELECT lyb.last_yard_bay,
                   lyr.last_yard_row,
                   0 top_tier
                   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                                last_yard_bay
                                FROM max_tier) lyb
                        CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('00A'),
                                           ('00B'),
                                           ...
                                           ('00G')) lyr (last_yard_row)
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                            FROM max_tier mt
                                            WHERE mt.last_yard_bay = lyb.last_yard_bay
                                                  AND mt.last_yard_row = lyr.last_yard_row);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Thank you @sticky bit !!

Comment: I want to do this for each `last_yard_park`. for info every `last_yard_park` has its own `last_yard_bay`s

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty much the same as your last question, with the table name changed and filtering different.  You don't have aggregation, so it is somewhat different, but the solution is very similar:

```
SELECT lyb.LAST_YARD_BAY, lyr.LAST_YARD_ROW, 
       COALESCE(mt.LAST_YARD_TIER, 0) as MAX_TIER
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LAST_YARD_BAY FROM MAX_TIER) lyb CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT LAST_YARD_ROW FROM MAX_TIER) lyr LEFT JOIN
     MAX_TIER mt
     ON mt.LAST_YARD_BAY = lyb.LAST_YARD_BAY AND
        mt.LAST_YARD_ROW = lyr.LAST_YARD_ROW 
ORDER BY lyr.LAST_YARD_BAY, lyr.LAST_YARD_ROW;
```

This assumes that all bays and rows you want are in the table.  If not, you can use a table constructor (i.e. `VALUES()`) to generate them.